# How to prevent the scroll event from being intercepted by a PopupWindow

Tags: android, onclick, android-popupwindow

When I click the space outside the `PopupWindow`, the window is dismissed. However, if I want to scroll a `ListView` outside the window, the scroll event is first recognized as a click event, and get intercepted by the window, so the window get dismissed, while the scroll is not executed.

How can I scroll the `ListView` **at the same time the window get dismissed**, so that i don't need to scroll it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this set of properties:

```
    window.setTouchable(true);
    window.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    window.setFocusable(false);
```

in this case your popup won't be dismissed when you click outside of its frame, but you can add a listener to catch outside touches and dismiss the popup:

```
    window.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                window.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```